# How to get first item only from a foreach loop of a List ViewModel in a razor view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor-pages

My razor view is bound to a ListViewModel delivered by an ActionResult controller; see below code snippets:

Viewmodel

```
    public class TicketItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public int? TicketId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Posted { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult TicketHistoryC(int ticketId)
    {
        var ticket = UnitOfWork.GetById<Ticket>(ticketId);

        var entities = UnitOfWork.GetAll<TicketItem>().Where(u => u.TicketId == ticketId).OrderByDescending(u => u.Posted).ToList();

        List<TicketItemViewModel> listModel = new List<TicketItemViewModel>();

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            TicketItemViewModel model = new TicketItemViewModel();
            model.Body = entity.Body;
            model.Posted = entity.Posted;
            model.UserId = entity.UserId;
            model.TicketId = entity.TicketId;
            model.Id = entity.Id;
            model.Title = ticket.Title.ToString();
            listModel.Add(model);
        }

        return View(listModel);
    }
```

In the top part of the view I want to show the property of the first item of the ViewModel. Below is my best try:

```
@model IEnumerable<Presentation.Host.Models.TicketItemViewModel>

@{int i = 0;}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h2>
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

**The code works but I wonder if there is a better or more efficient way to get the first item only?**

Comment: use a for loop... or SELECT TOP (1)

Comment: I tried to use a for loop, but got  syntax errors in the @html part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Linq` and first check if your `Model` has at lease one record then use `Model.First()` to get first record.

```
@model IEnumerable<Presentation.Host.Models.TicketItemViewModel>

@if (Model.Any())
{
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.First().Title)</h2>
}
```

---

**Edit** : Alternatively we can use `Model.Take(1)` as well.

[Enumerable.Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-7.0) : Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence.

```
@model IEnumerable<Presentation.Host.Models.TicketItemViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model.Take(1))
{
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.First().Title)</h2>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the first element of the list with:

```
Model.First();
```

And the rest of the list with:

```
Model.Skip(1);
```

Comment: Very useful! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```
var IstItem = Model.First();
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    // do something with each item
    if (result.Equals(IstItem))
    {
        // do something different with the last item
    }
    else
    {
        // do something different with every item but the last
    }
}
```